# Show infinite custom posts in wp admin

Tags: pagination, custom-post-type, wp-admin

I need to see all custom posts on the admin list, rather than paginating at 20, like usual. Please note, this is only for a custom post type called "gallery".

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! In the top right of the posts list in wp-admin, there is a "Screen Options" button. You can modify the amount of posts shown there!